# Is there a heuristic for homogenizing image dimensions before using them to train neural net?

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am training a neural net on a set of images with heterogeneous dimensions. Of course, they all have to have the same dimensions to be fed to the NN, and it is simple enough to use `scipy.misc.imresize()` for this. But, how should I choose width and height? My first instinct was to plot histograms of both and eyeball values around the 75th percentile. I also thought maybe I should scale all images up to the max values for both height and width, so that no details are discarded from the higher-pixel images. Is there a best practice for addressing this problem? Thanks!

For reference, I am using `python 2.7` and `keras` with `theano` backend and dimension ordering.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a standard approach on this. In machine learning, in many cases we have to try and see.

- If I were you, if I had to build a custom neural network, I would start with mean image size and then I would gradually increase the size until reaching optimum score.
- If you are using a pretrained neural network then just resize your images to network's default.